How to read and change value of edge crease in blender 4 via python script (MeshEdge.crease property has been removed)
as MeshEdge.crease property has been removed in blender 4, how can I check and change the value of an edge crease ?
I used to do this to check edge crease value and set it to 1 if the value was over 0.1 in blender 3.x
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        
        me = obj.data
        obj.select_set(True)                       
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

        for e in me.edges:
            
            if e.crease > 0.1:
                e.select = True
                print (obj.name, e.crease)
                e.crease = 1

Thanks

You can edit the attribute in edit mode but you have to use bmesh :
import bpy
import bmesh


for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        if obj.mode == "EDIT":        
            mesh = obj.data        
            attribute = mesh.attributes["crease_edge"]

            bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
            crease_layer = bm.edges.layers.float.get(attribute.name)

            for edge in bm.edges:
                if edge[crease_layer] > 0.1:
                    edge[crease_layer] = 1

            bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
        else:
            print("See other answer")


It seems to have moved to an attribute called "crease_edge", but the data only seems to be valid in Object Mode.
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        
        me = obj.data
        obj.select_set(True)                       
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        
        for e in me.attributes["crease_edge"].data:
      
            if e.value > 0.1:
                print (obj.name, e.value)
                e.value = 1

